# Redirect URL without hash - Ember.JS

Tags: javascript, url, ember.js, hash, ember-router

I'm working on a Ember.JS app using

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'hash'
});
```

Which means that all my URLs are something like these:

- http://example.com/#/
- http://example.com/#/abc
- http://example.com/#/def/ghi/123

**The issue:**

In a very specific case, the user will try to access my application using:

- http://example.com/abc (yes, without the hash)

**My question:**

Is it possible to redirect this user from:

- http://example.com/abc

to

- http://example.com/#/abc

using the `router.js` file or a similar approach such as use `.htdocs` in a PHP app to redirect URLs?

Comment: That would need to happen on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank all for the help!!

Here it is how I solved the issue:

We just added a redirect in the Nginx server. In case you use apache, you can also do that on its configuration.

```
location /abc {
    rewrite ^.* http://example.com/#/abc redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless the webserver actually serves the Ember App when visiting `example.com/abc`, there is nothing you can do from the Ember side, because the code never gets to execute.